# Where does the Google Sign-in API system stores data and in what type?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-signin

I already installed all of the necessary requirements to create authorisations for Google sign-in via Google Cloud Platform.

My question is what type of data can I retrieve from the users who sign-in with their Google accounts, where can I set what kind of data to retrieve from the users and where the data will actually be stored to access.

The web application is currently on `test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GAPI Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetbasicprofile) has detailed information on the basic profile properties that all applications that use Google Sign-In can access.

In addition to the Basic Profile you can add additional `Scopes` while creating the `OAuth Client`, for example there is a scope to retrieve the users `phone number`.

Storage of data is not configurable by the user, the GAPI lib may store data on the client side but this is stored securely and is not configurable via the client lib. If you must  store the users detail in a way that is unique to your application, then you should handle this in your application code, do note this is not recommended